# use CASE without ELSE in WHERE clause like IF

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to use a CASE without ELSE in WHERE clause like an IF? for put a condition or not.

Example

```
WHERE monto = 100
    AND CASE WHEN @canal is not null
        THEN canal = @canal
    END
```

I ask this because I want to do this

```
WHERE monto = 100
    IF (@canal is not null){
        AND canal = @canal
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include this condition in the `WHERE`:

`WHERE monto = 100 AND ( @canal IS NULL OR canal = @canal )`

If it's actually in a stored-procedure it might be more efficient if you use an `IF...ELSE` around the different queries, one with this parameter and one without.

Comment: Do you think to do 2 times the query is more efficient?

Comment: @FelipePincheira: what means "do the query two times"? If it's in a stored-prodcedure use `IF...ELSE`. But how large is the table at all? If you don't have a performance issue you don't need to change it.